# how do I make a list of tuples from a string?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

> Write a function
>
> `def parseAnnotation(annotation):`
>
> that takes a string `annotation` as argument. This string describes the location of the CDS in the sequence in the following manner (start..end),(start..end) etc. E.g. the string `'(459..521),(1834..2736)'` specifies that the CDS is distributed in two exons with one part from base number 459 to base number 521 (both inclusive) and the remaining part from base number 1834 to base number 2736 (both inclusive). The function must return a list with a tuple for each CDS part, each with a start and end value.
>
> Example usage:
> `parseAnnotation('(459..521),(1834..2736)')`
> should return
> `[(459, 521), (1834, 2736)]`

My try:

```
def parseAnnotation(annotation):
lst = []
for seq in annotation:
    seq.replace("..", ",")
    lst = seq
    return annotation
    
print parseAnnotation('(459..521), (1834..2736)')
```

output:

```
(459..521), (1834..2736)
```

What can I do?

Comment: What is CDS, exon and base number?

Comment: It is biological terms for the data. CDS is the frame the coding sequence of a DNA sequence is read in, in this case from 459 to 521 and 1834 to 2736. An exon is one of these, fx. 459 to 521. And 459 alone is a base number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def stripString(ann):
    return ann.strip().lstrip("(").rstrip(")").split("..")

def parseAnnotation(ann):
    return [tuple(map(int, stripString(j))) for j in ann.split(",")]

print parseAnnotation('(459..521),(1834..2736)')
```

**Output**

```
[(459, 521), (1834, 2736)]
```

**Explanation**

First, the `parseAnnotation` is called with `(459..521),(1834..2736)`. It split the entire string based on `,`. So, we will get `['(459..521)', '(1834..2736)']`. Then it picks element by element and does the following. (For explanation, I ll take `(459..521)`.

`stripString` function is called with `(459..521)` where, first `strip()` is applied which removes all the unnecessary whitespace characters on both the sides. Then, the whitespace stripped string is subjected to `lstrip("(")` and `rstrip(")")` which remove `(` from the left side of the string and `)` from the right hand side of the string, respectively. So, the current string becomes `'459..521'`. Now it is split based on `..`, so we will get `['459', '521']` from the `stripString` function. Now, that the function call is over, the expression becomes like this

```
tuple(map(int, ['459', '521']))
```

Since the numbers are actually in string format, we convert them to numbers with `int` function. So, we ll get `tuple([459, 521])` and which will give `(459, 521)`

Comment: Do I need to make both functions?

Comment: @bronsje Yup. Breaking the tasks into two functions, is to increase the readability.

Comment: so the first function splits the string in two and the second makes it in to a tuple?

Comment: @bronsje The `stripSting`, strips `(`, `)`, unnecessary spaces and then splits the string based on `..`. The second function, converts each splitted data into a number and forms a tuple with `tuple` function.

Comment: @bronsje Please check my answer now. I have added little explanation

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable, you should assign the string returned by `str.replace` to a variable.

```
>>> s = '(459..521), (1834..2736)'
>>> new_s = s.replace('..', ',')
>>> new_s
'(459,521), (1834,2736)'
>>> s                          #Still unchanged
'(459..521), (1834..2736)'
```

To get a list of tuples use `ast.literal_eval` and `list()`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> list(literal_eval(new_s))
[(459, 521), (1834, 2736)]
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is not so efficient like the solution of thefourtheye, but i just do it step by step and i got it. I just post it to show, how you can go on very simplified.

```
def parseAnnotation(ann):
    tmp = ann.replace('..', ',')  # remove .. from the tuple: '(123..123), (4321..8765)'
                                  #                          =>'(123, 123), (4321, 8765)'
    tmp = tmp.replace('(', '')    # remove ( from the string
    tmp = tmp.replace(')', '')    # remove ) from the string 
    tmp = tmp.replace(' ', '')    # remove spaces from the string to get something like that
                                  # '123,123,4321,8765'
    tmp = tmp.split(',')          # ['123', '123', '4321', '8765']
    return [(int(tmp[i]), int(tmp[i+1])) for i in range(len(tmp)-2)]
```

I just modify the string and then i put it together in a tuple. 
But unfortunately it's not so elegant and efficient like thefourtheye.